# Formatting axis label in high chart using dynamic values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, highcharts

I am using high chart to plot a graph.In x axis I am plotting integer values.i need to format the x axis label using date time which i have in data array.
`this.point.mydate` not working inside label formatter.

```
   xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 1,  
            min:1,
            max:30,
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                                  text: 'Date'
                            },  
                            labels: {
                formatter: function () { 

                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%d', this.point.mydate); 

                }
                } 
            },
```

Comment: In the labels you have no access to this.point, only for tick object. Please recreate your example as live demo, maybe [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) will be useful, to return ticks in points.

Comment: @SebastianBochan see i need to show formated labels instead of x axis value.I have a date array already

Comment: You can use a [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions) as array of xAxis ticks.

Comment: @SebastianBochan How we can set datetime as label for an axis if we have plotted graph with another data field?using tickPositions

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Why not convert the x values to the proper date time value before plotting?  If you're going to do the work to process the data like this, you might as well just do it once, before sending it to the chart, and then everything else will work by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have used **Date** in xAxis datatype , it should be **datetime** as follows.

```
xAxis: {        
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b', this.point.mydate);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Khoranjiya I am plotting axis with integer values and want to show axis label in date time

Comment: On what basis you want to calculate date from integer values

Comment: Khoranjiya function seriesItem(){var self= this;self.x= '',self.y= '',  self.high=0,  self.mydate='',self.total='',self.color=''} ; I am plotting graph with self.x on x axis and self.y on y axis.i have a date value in self.mydate.I want to show this date instead of x value in label

Comment: You can use setCategories() methods of HichCharts to set custom labels.

chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(timelines,false);

where timeline is the array containing your custom date values.